# Pasar el valor de un Input a un campo Json

Tags: php, javascript, json

quiero pasar el valor de un campo input tipo text (es un número) a un campo de un json pero no se como se hace.

Necesito pasar **total** al json campo **amount** por favor ayuda

Si me puede guiar como hacer o si tienen algun ejemplo como se hace porque la verdad investigué pero no entendí muy bien, leí sobre jsonSerialize y hacer un recorrido con el json para armarlo creo que era algo así

```js
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var order = {
     secret: "#",
     merchantId: "#",
     terminal: "#",
     amount: 1000,
     currency: "CRC",
     description: "Prueba de Pagos en Línea",
     orderReference: "0000791284",
     additional: {
      customer: {
       name: "User Example",
       email: "v.zamora@cabletica.com",
       billingAddress: {
        country: "CR",
        province: "San José",
        city: "Curridabat",
        street1: "Freses"
       },
       shippingAddress: {
        country: "CR",
        province: "San José",
        city: "Curridabat",
        street1: "Frese"
       }
      },
      products: [{
       description: "Descripción de producto",
       skuId: "Identificador único en el comercio",
       quantity: 1,
       price: 100.00,
       type: "Tipo de producto"
      }
     
      /*{
       description: "Descripción de producto",
       skuId: "Identificador único en el comercio",
       quantity: 1,
       price: 100.00,
       type: "Tipo de producto"
      }
     
      {
       description: "Descripción de producto",
       skuId: "Identificador único en el comercio",
       quantity: 1,
       price: 100.00,
       type: "Tipo de producto"
      }*/]
     }
    } 
                    postData("#widgetNoModal", order)
    });
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" id="total" class="form-control" readonly value="0.0" style="width: 100px !important;"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo pudes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
order.amount= Number(document.getElementById('total').value);
```

El document.getElementById('total') obtiene un elemento del DOM de Html por su Id en este caso es 'total' con el .value obtenemos el valor de dicho elemento del DOM. y la funcion Number ya a convertir el que obtuvimos del input en un Numero ya que este lo retorna como un String.